# Nuxt3. Dynamic layout change

Tags: layout, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to dynamically switch layouts and load the desired layout when a person enters the site via a direct link.

I use the guide ([v3.nuxtjs.org/guide](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/layouts/)) where it says to add the following piece of code

```js
const route = useRoute()
function enableCustomLayout() {
   route.meta.layout = "custom"
}
definePageMeta({
   layout: false
});
```

This solves the problem when the site is loaded but creates another problem. When the site loads, layouts take a long time to load.

[image: Lag gif]

How to solve this problem and achieve the desired result?

[I created a stackblitz project with sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-mq5ezw?file=README.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use `definePageMeta`.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-page-meta

Use `NuxtLayout`:

```js
// ~/app.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

File in `layouts` foldernamed `default` will be loaded if no layout is specified.

```js
// ~/layouts/default.vue
<template>
  <h1>Default Layout</h1>
  <slot />
</template>
```

Create more layouts with any name...

```js
// ~/layouts/custom.vue
<template>
  <h1>My Custom Layout</h1>
  <slot />
</template>
```

Use `definePageMeta` in a content page to specify a `layout` name that matches the file name of a layout in the `layouts` directory.

```js
// ~/pages/index.vue

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'custom'
})
</script>

<template>

  <div>
    Content page using specific layout
  </div>

</template>
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts

Answer (score 0):

In your app.vue you can do something similar to this

```
  <script setup lang="ts">
  
  const userLayout = "user";
  const adminLayout = "admin";
  const propertiesLayout = "properties";
  // check route and set layout
  const route = useRoute();
  const layout = computed(() => {
    if (route.path.includes("/admin")) {
      return adminLayout;
    } else if (route.path.includes("/properties")) {
      return propertiesLayout;
    } else {
      return userLayout;
    }
  });

  </script>
<template>
  
  <NuxtLayout :name="layout"> </NuxtLayout>
</template>
<style > </style>
```